# Configure dapr log level in Azure Container App

Tags: azure, logging, dapr, azure-container-apps

How do I configure the Dapr log level in an [Azure Container App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview)?  It defaults to `info` & I want to set it to `debug`.

Reference: [Configure and view Dapr Logs](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/troubleshooting/logs-troubleshooting/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable Darp in Container App then you can config the log level there

[image]